# Possible to display available sizes in the product tile in Shoper

Tags: smarty

Is possible to show for example all available size in product tile? I use variant product with magazine support. Product without magazine support show on main page, category page in suitable product tile information about available size but product with magazine support show all size, also not available. I can't get any info about stock variant product, which allow me remove unnecessary info. [product tile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwtoh.png)

First product is variant with magazine support, size 46 is not available (stock 0)
Second - product without magazine support

I have to be able to manage for example stock product variant because using magazine support

```html
{assign var=options value=$product->getOptionsConfigurationStruct()}
  {if $product->product->group_id && count($options)}
    <div class="size-values-product">
    {foreach from=$options item=option}
      {if ($option.name|escape == 'Rozmiar')}
        {foreach from=$option.values item=value}
          <span value="{$value.id|escape}">{$value.name|escape}</span>
        {/foreach}
      {/if}                                                         
    {/foreach}
    </div>
  {/if}
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Do I good understand that you want to show only avaible size numbers? (not all of them?)

Comment: that's right :)

Comment: I would debug `$product` and see what is there, maybe there is information about stock availability so then you can if/else to not show them.

Comment: As @r_a_f said use {$product|print_r} and check available fields.